# You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Guys I have this code in my App.js:

```
  return (
  <div className="App">
    
    
      <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Index />} />
      
      <Route path="/404" element={<Err404 />} />
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
      <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      
      </Routes>
  </div>
);
```

And I added the BrowserRouter in the index.js like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './pages/App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
<React.StrictMode>
<BrowserRouter>
<App />
</BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
);
```

But I still get that error above in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May you check all components in your Route?

```
<Index />
<Err404 />
<Contact />}
<Register />
<Login />} />
```

It seems that one of them contains Router or BrowserRouter, etc component.

**[Updated]** - if you are interested this is the line with that error in codebase - https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx#L181

it checks if your Router component (e.g. BrowserRouter) is created in context of another Router component and throw this error

Comment: okay i checked all the components and the pages found some BrowserRouter and removed them and i removed everything that has to do with the library react-router-dom and i still get the same error :/

Comment: man, can not help you more as do not see your code. But the error you asked due to nested Routers components. I am 100 sure

Comment: yes yes im sure i was working with react-router-dom v5 and it was working fine then i decided to use the v6 so i installed the package i changed my code and now this happend

Comment: okay bro its solved, someone here told me to remove routes from the app.js and i forgot to put them back, but your solution is the one that fixed the problem its because there was some BrowserRouter in my pages ty